# Create a Mongoose Schema of type Array of Maps

Tags: javascript, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a mongoose schema that is an array of Maps that are String -> String:

```
var daySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schedule:  {
        type: [Map], 
        of: String
    }
});
```

This is what I have, but it's giving me a validation error.

Comment: Add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a separate schema for the maps and then use that schema in an array:

```
var Schedule = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: Map,
    of: String
});

var daySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: [Schedule]
});
```

As shown in the [array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) examples.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work at least with mongoose 6.6. This just creates a schema with the literal keys `type` and `of`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var daySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schedule:  {
        type: [{type: Map, of: String}], 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Solution for Mongoose 6.x.x**

```
var daySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schedule:  {
        type: [{myKey1:String, myKey2:String}], 
        
    }
});`
```